# Python Check list line by line

Tags: python, list, if-statement, search

My problem is following:

```
def searchWordlist():
path = str(raw_input(PATH))
word = str(raw_input(WORD))
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        if word in line:
            print "Word found"
```

Than I added following code:

```
else:
    print "Word not found"
```

But this obviously can't work, because it will print "Word not found" until the word is found. Well.. but how can I print that the word is not found?! I srsly don't know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make a variable to keep track of whether or not the word was found while you're inside the loop and then check that variable after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def searchWordlist():    
    path = str(raw_input(PATH))
    word = str(raw_input(WORD))
    loc = -1
    with open(path) as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if word in line:
                loc = i
                break
    if loc >= 0:
        print ("Word found at line {}".format(loc))
    else:
        print ("Word not found")
```

As a bonus, this keeps track of where in the file the word in first seen, if at all.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Python has a special trick for this kind of thing:

```
for line in f:
    if word in line:
        print "Word found"
        break
else:
    print "Word not found"
```

Here the `else` goes with the `for`, and specifically executes if the loop completes normally without hitting a `break`.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want it to do is to print whether `word` is found in any of the lines:

```
def searchWordlist():    
    path = str(raw_input(PATH))
    word = str(raw_input(WORD))
    with open(path) as f:
        if any(word in line for line in f):
            print('Word found')
        else:
            print('Word not found')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your function to return as soon as it finds the word if you only need to find the first occurrence. This has the added bonus of not having to loop through the whole file if it doesnt need to

```
def searchWordlist():
  path = str(raw_input(PATH))
  word = str(raw_input(WORD))
  with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
      if word in line:
        print "Word found"
        return 1
  print "Word not found"
  return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def searchWordlist():
    found_word = False
    path = str(raw_input(PATH))
    word = str(raw_input(WORD))
    with open(path) as f:
        for line in f:
            if word in line:
                print "Word found"
                found_word = True
    if not found_word:
        print "Word not found!"
```

What this code does is it executes your code as normal, except that if it finds the word it sets a boolean to true, signifying that it has found the word. It then, after completely parsing the file, sees if the word was found, if the variable is true. If the word was not found, then it prints that the word was not found. If you want the code to stop after the word is found for the first time, but `break` after `found_word = True`.